# Pass a file to xlrd.open_workbook()

Tags: python, django

I am trying to open a file with xlrd.open_workbook() but am getting an error:

```
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile
```

Here's my code:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_file(request.FILES['file'])

def handle_file(f):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(f)
```

What's the correct way to pass a file?

**UPDATE**

Found a solution:

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=f.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the path, instead of the file.

To access the path of the uploaded file, I usually do:

```
uploaded_file = request.FILES["file"]
fs = FileSystemStorage()
name = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
path = fs.path(name)
```

Import file system storage like this

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
```

You can delete the file, in case you don't need it, this way

```
fs.delete(name)
```

Hope that helps.

---